# C#: How to use RichTextBox.Select() method?

Tags: c#, select, methods, richtextbox

```cs
richTextBox1.Select(0, 1);
richTextBox1.Select();
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Yellow;
```

This snippet results in the whole text becoming yellow, but I actually want only the specified characters to become Yellow. How can I do that?

Comment: The snippet results the first character become yellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the Select method only once,passing the two arguments for the text range:

```
richTextBox1.Select(0, 1); 
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
richTextBox1.Select(0, 5);
richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
```